# Use command line to upload insert script, always get error unable to read script

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am trying to keep my mobile services scripts in my project so I can use soruce control on them. However when I try to execute the command I always get this error.

```
"azure : error:   Unable to read script from file ./table/<tablename>.insert.js"
```

I have installed the tools and imported my publishing settings. Odd thing is though whenever I do "azure mobile list" it says I have no mobile services account. I know I do though because I am working with it in the portal and in Visual Studio. I am executing the following command in the package management console.

```
"azure mobile script upload <mobile service> table/<table>.insert.js"
```

and get the above noted error.

In my VS project the table folder is a root folder (created directly under my project).

if I do:

```
"azure mobile script upload <mobile service> /table/<table>.insert.js"
```

I get:

```
"azure : error:   Invalid script name '/table/<tablename>.insert.js'"
```

I have verified my script name is in the same case as my table and also tried it in all lower case. I have also make sure everyone has permissions to the file.

Comment: For the problem with `azure mobile list` not showing any services, do you have multiple subscriptions? Try typing `azure account list`... if you have multiple, it's possible that your service is not in the *default* subscription. If that's the case, set the subscription which contains your mobile services (`azure account set <subscription>`, where `<subscription>` is the GUID associated with the one you want.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. It in fact was not the default. I changed it to the default and it now lists my mobile service. However, it still will not upload my script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax (line breaks added for clarity, don't add them to your command line):

```
azure mobile script upload
    <mobile service name>
    table/<tablename>.insert
    -f ./table/<tablename>.insert.js
```

The argument after the mobile service name is the script on the service (the insert script for your table) and the next one is the actual file (preceded by the `-f` or `--file` option) in your computer which you want to upload. That means that in theory you could have a local file with a different name (e.g., my-insert-script-for-table-orders.js), not that I'd recommend anyone to do that.

Comment: hmm actually if I give it the full path with -f in the command line it works. Not sure why it is not finding relative path.

Comment: got relative to work (was missing one ndoe in the relative path it needed). Still will not work without the -f switch like [MSDN says](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/command-line-administration/#register-script) but at least it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the MSDN link, I'll forward it to the people responsible to get that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'unable to read script' is given when the file can not be found/read, it is using the node fs module, readFileSync(file, 'utf8') behind the scenes.

If the file doesn't exist in 'table/table.insert.js' then you can manually specify the path using the -f flag, like azure mobile script upload table/table.insert.js -f file.

If the file does exist, then it's probably failing due to the file not correctly being utf8 encoded. Verify your file does not contain any invalid characters in it for utf8.

Also, since you mentioned you are using source control, instead of using the CLI, you can directly use Git to update and push your changes to your mobile service.